# Get related questions to the original question recursively

Tags: support, feature-request

Is there, or could there be, some way to recursively pull/e-mail/get questions related to the related questions to a specific question?

Related questions are shown in the sidebar and are automatically identified by the system.

For example, if you specify a depth of 1, that would return all question related to the original.  A depth of 2 would pull (e-mail?) all questions related to the first set, etc.

Or, just generate a list of depth n.  For practical purposes, a depth of three seems about as far as I, personally, would want to take it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's an [API method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-questions), which returns the related questions to a question. Given a question ID, you'd just need to recursively iterate through results.

Read about [batching requests](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/vectors) to avoid the rate limits catching you; this might return a lot of posts. Enough posts that I'd question its utility.

Comment: The large number of posts is probably because related to related to related does not mean that the start and the end is related. One may need to examine the related algorithm and what goes in there (even behavior of users might be a criteria) to achieve something more useful.